# Installing Nagios 4.0.2 on Centos 7 - service fails to start

Tags: nagios, centos7

Having followed the instructions here http://linoxide.com/how-tos/install-configure-nagios-centos-7/ (but downloading Nagios 4.0.2 instead of 4.0.7 - I have to use that version), I have reached a point where the Nagios service won't start.

The commands I'm trying are -

```
[root@my-server]# service nagios start
Starting nagios (via systemctl):  Job for nagios.service failed. See 'systemctl status     nagios.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
                                                       [FAILED]

[root@my-server]# systemctl status nagios.service
nagios.service - LSB: start and stop Nagios monitoring server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Wed 2014-11-05 11:40:27 GMT; 1min 0s ago
  Process: 23314 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/nagios start (code=exited, status=5)

Nov 05 11:40:27 centos-server systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop Nagios monitoring server...
Nov 05 11:40:27 centos-server nagios[23314]: nagios is stopped
Nov 05 11:40:27 centos-server systemd[1]: PID file /var/nagios/nagios.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
Nov 05 11:40:27 centos-server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop Nagios monitoring server.
Nov 05 11:40:27 centos-server systemd[1]: Unit nagios.service entered failed state.
```

That `/var/nagios/nagios.pid` file doesn't exist. Initially, the `/var/nagios` directory didn't exist, so I created it. I've tried changing its owner to `nagios` and I've tried changing its owner to `root`.

If I create an empty pid file then try starting the service again I get an error saying it contains an invalid value, then it gets deleted.

Also interesting - I couldn't verify the Nagios config as suggested in those instructions because `/usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios` doesn't exist. Not sure what's happened to that.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this appeared to be re-running the various `make install-*` commands. I didn't see any errors during the first install, but it looks like some aspects failed anyway - most notably the missing `/usr/local/nagios/bin` directory.

After that `service nagios start` hangs for several minutes, then claims to have timed out. Despite this, Nagios seems to be running.

I also had to open port 80.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are installing using `yum` from EPEL. If you install from source, the files may be in different locations but the ideas are the same. Make sure the `nagios` user has permission to these files.

> That /var/nagios/nagios.pid file doesn't exist. Initially, the
>   /var/nagios directory didn't exist, so I created it.

Look for this section in `/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg`

```
# LOCK FILE
# This is the lockfile that Nagios will use to store its PID number
# in when it is running in daemon mode.
lock_file=/var/run/nagios/nagios.pid
```

That is the file Nagios will create when it starts up. Older versions might use `nagios.lock`, or the path might be something like `/usr/local/nagios/`

> If I create an empty pid file then try starting the service again I
>   get an error saying it contains an invalid value, then it gets
>   deleted.

You shouldn't do this! `systemd` will create/delete it on it's own.

`systemd` specifies the pid file it is looking for in `/lib/systemd/system/nagios.service`

```
PIDFile=/var/run/nagios/nagios.pid
```

This needs to be the same as `lock_file` in your `nagios.cfg`, or `systemd` will timeout and stop your `nagios` service.

> Also interesting - I couldn't verify the Nagios config as suggested in
>   those instructions because /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios doesn't exist.
>   Not sure what's happened to that.

Run the command `whereis nagios` to find it. It's likely located in `/usr/sbin/nagios`

If you want to see related messages to this issue, run `fgrep 'systemd' messages | fgrep -i nagios` from `/var/log/`